# Rspec any_instance should_receive should have received the following messages but didn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, update-attributes

I'm having an issue with a scaffold test for rspec where any_instance.should_receive is throwing an error: Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
       Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: update_attributes

Rspec code, using FactoryGirl and strong_parameters:

```
describe "PUT update" do
   describe "with valid params" do
     it "updates the requested acquisition" do
       puts "starting updates the requested acquisition"
       acquisition = create(:acquisition)
       # Assuming there are no other acquisitions in the database, this
       # specifies that the Acquisition created on the previous line
       # receives the :update_attributes message with whatever params are
       # submitted in the request.
       Acquisition.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with(:acquisition =>    {:person_id => '10'})
      puts "before the put "
       put :update, :id => acquisition.id, :acquisition => { :person_id => '10'}
       puts "ending the updates the requested acquisition"
     end   
  end
end
```

Controller code:

```
def update
    @acquisition = Acquisition.find(params[:id])
    puts "acquisition is #{@acquisition.inspect}"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @acquisition.update_attributes!(acquisition_params)
        puts "updated the thing! #{@acquisition.inspect}"
        format.html { redirect_to(@acquisition, :notice => 'Acquisition was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        puts "failed to update the thing!"
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @acquisition.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Test outputs:

```
starting updates the requested acquisition
before the put
acquisition is #<Acquisition id: 502, sample_id: 7, person_id: 7, method: nil>
params is acqusition_params is {"person_id"=>"10"}
updated the thing! #<Acquisition id: 502, sample_id: 7, person_id: 10, method: nil>
ending the updates the requested acquisition
F

1) AcquisitionsController PUT update with valid params updates the requested acquisition
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: update_attributes
```

Given that I'm printing out the updated object in my controller and it's correct, why is the test failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a typo in your paste, but in case it is not, your test should test if `update_attributes!` is received, not `update_attributes`

```
Acquisition.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes!)
```

Comment: Ugh.  Simple typos suck.  I also had to change my rspec code to:
Acquisition.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes!).with("person_id" => '10'), but this helped me figure the rest out.  Thanks.